# JQuery datepicker control - how to increase/decrease the date by 1 day on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am not a JQuery expert and below is the use case i am expecting on my web page -

I Have a JQuery datepicker control embedded on the web page as below -

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Converted to the Datepicker control -

```
$(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                defaultDate: date,
                onSelect: function () {
                    selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
                    selDate = selectedDate;
                    console.log(selectedDate);
                }
            });
        });
```

Now its fine till now as i can see the control, fetch the date and all.

Problem starts when i place a next/prev button to increase and decrease the value of the datepicker by 1 day. Below is the code that i have put so far -

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", ($("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate() - 1));
```

I am calling the above code on click of a button.

As a result of this, date is changing but not by 1 day rather some random number of dates.

Not sure what exactly i am missing here and any help on this will be really useful.

I have been exploring a lot of related SO questions and also checked some of the solutions earlier accepted, but somehow they are not working correctly either.

Please suggest.

AJ

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var date_new = $('#datepicker').datepicker ('getDate'); 
    date_new.setDate (date_new.getDate () + 1); 

$('#datepicker').datepicker ('setDate', date_new);
```

For more informations [Click here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate).

Comment: Ok just saw. Let me give it a shot and let u know.